# How can I improve my logic/code this to calculate a percentage correctly?

Tags: java, arrays, percentage

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class a4
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int Faculty[]=new int[4];
        int Student[]=new int[4];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int index=0, f=0, s=0;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Pickelball tournament");
        System.out.println("There can be only one winner per game. Wnner score is max 11. Scoring starts from 0. ");
        do
        {
                System.out.println("Game# " +  (index+1));
                System.out.println("Enter the scores for faculty: ");
                f=sc.nextInt();
                //
                System.out.println("Enter the scores for student: ");
                s=sc.nextInt();
                if((f==11) && (s==11))
                {
                    System.out.println("Only one team may score 11; try again.");
                }
                else if(((f<11) && (s<11)) || ((f>11) && (s>11)) || ((f<0) && (s<0)))
                {
                    System.out.println("One team must score 11 to proceed.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Faculty[index]=f;
                    Student[index]=s;
                    index++;
                }

        }while(index<4);


        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\t\tGame# " + i);
        }
        System.out.print("\nFaculty score \n\t\t");
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(Faculty[i] + "\t\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\nStudent score \n\t\t");
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(Student[i] + "\t\t");
        }

        int winningPercent=0;
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            if(Faculty[i]==11)
            {
                Faculty[i]=1;
                Faculty[i]++;
            }
            winningPercent= ((Faculty[i]/4)*100);
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nFaculty won " + winningPercent + "% of their matches");
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble to figure out the logic on how to make my code print out the percentages I want. For example, if 11 is input once, then I'd want it to display that the faculty's chances of winning are 25%; if it is input twice, then that goes up to 50%. I'm not sure how to fix my logic in the last part of my code because I thought that from what I wrote, if `Faculty[i]==11` then it would reinitialize to 1 then keep adding 1 based on if Faculty[i] was 11, then take a value 1-4 and divide it by 4 to get a percentage (either 0, 25, 50, 75, or 100). What I've tried is moving my winningPercent statement inside my if statement but that would usually give me 0% or 200%. What my code is doing right now is if 11 is input once or twice, it goes up to 100% already, which is inaccurate.

Comment: So, 11 input 0 times = 0, 11 input 1 time = 25, 11 input 2 times = 50, etc? What will happen if 11 is inputted 5 times? if 11 isn't inputted?

Comment: @AyushGarg my code is supposed to only accept 4 rounds and requires that either team is supposed to score 11.

Comment: Inside of your `while` loop keep track of how many rounds are won by each team then divide by 4